# Is there a standard Control for an action list popover like in Files app?

Tags: ios, uikit

Is it a some standard control used in the iOS Files app for action list popover when you longpress on a file:

[image]

If there is no standard control for this, what is the simplest way to make it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your screen shot shows the UIMenuController with UIMenuItems. See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uimenucontroller

Comment: See https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/70e9543f1150bb0acc6276895bfbbf9d483fd2ad/bk2ch08p466decorationView/ch21p748collectionViewFlowLayout2/ViewController.swift for downloadable example